# adding existing jni libraries (already compiled ".so") to another android studio project

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I haven't found anyone who has been able to answer my specific question online. I have an old Android project that I want to copy some .so libraries from and paste them into a new project. I'm new to this stuff and I know I need to tell my new program where to find these libraries but I don't know if I should be using CMake or NDK to import alreay compiled code. This is what my directory looks like:

[image]

I call for this library in my program like this:

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("serial_port");
    }
```

But how do I tell the compiler where to find these copied and pasted files?

I started a file based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html) from Android but I'm confused about a few things. This is what I have so far:

```
# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build your native library.
# This ensures that a certain set of CMake features is available to
# your build.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Specifies a library name, specifies whether the library is STATIC or
# SHARED, and provides relative paths to the source code. You can
# define multiple libraries by adding multiple add.library() commands,
# and CMake builds them for you. When you build your app, Gradle
# automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
             serial_port

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             IMPORTED

             serial_port/src/${ANDROID_ABI}/libserial_port.so

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/libs/armeabi/libserial_port.so )
```

I don't think I'm doing it right. Please take a look and point me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to keep them inside the dir `jniLibs` in their respective folders.

eg.

/app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libserial_port.so

And you don't need to use any other tools like CMake to use them. You can directly load them.

Comment: Will it work even with my sub-directories (x86, armeabi)?  I have tried this before but android studio couldn’t recognize the open method I was calling when I loaded my library. When I call System.loadLibrary(“serial_port”) it doesn’t seem to recognize this library. PS I didn’t write this library. I’m taking it from a sample program that a manufacturer sent me. I’m trying to access a serial port to get access to an internal printer on a POS system. In the sample program they call private static native FileDescriptor open(String path, int baudrate, int flags, boolean flowCon)

Comment: Android studio will not recognize. But it will run if you place the so files in their respective directories.

Comment: By the way, you cannot place the static native methods anywhere you like. I hope you are declaring them in the proper class in proper package. Place them exactly where they are in the sample program.

Comment: so I changed my directory to store the sub-folders in jniLibs and got rid of the cpp and libs folders. Now 3 subfolders (armeabi, armeabi-v7, x86) are stored in jniLibs which is inside main. Do I need to add the three sub directories in the path and do i use ( jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs'] ) as suggested by @srs or do I use ( jniLibs.srcDirs = ['jniLibs'] ) ? I'm new to this. I wish I could just read the file. I would write it in Java now that Java has become efficient at these operations. In other words, what would you place in the app/build.gradle to get to my new Libraries?

Comment: No you don't need to do that. The default location is okay.

Comment: one more comment and thank you for all your help!! :) What about loading the files. I load like this:  System.loadLibrary("serial_port");  How does Android know what I mean?

Comment: default location?  is it  jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']      or       jniLibs.srcDirs = ['jniLibs']

Comment: You don't need to do anything in gradle, if you place them inside jniLibs. And `System.loadLibrary` is a java method to look for and load the native libraries.

Comment: what about the "serial_port" parameter in loadLibrary?

Comment: It looks for the file "lib"+ parameter +".so"

Answer (score 1):

Default JNI forlder for Android Studio is **jniLibs**. If you put your native libraries inside this folder then it will automatically added to app build path.

In your case, you have put the native codes in **libs** folder. To make it work you must specify your new JNI path in **app/build.gradle** file. You can use the following gradle script for that:---

```
android{

   sourceSets {
       main {
           jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
       }
   }    

}
```

Comment: What about loading the files. I load like this: System.loadLibrary("serial_port"); How does Android know what I mean when I call "serial_port"?

Comment: When you call System.loadLibrary("Abc"), then android system will load libAbc.so file from the proper architecture subfolder. So if you place your (armeabi, armeabi-v7, x86) folders inside the default app jni directory("app/src/main/jniLibs"), then you can just call System.loadLibrary("serial_port"). It will work. Do not need to change jni path in gradle.