# How to add already compiled C code to android studio project?

Tags: java, android-studio, java-native-interface

After having already checked this [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178438/how-to-add-already-compiled-c-library-to-android) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45118175/how-to-add-jni-c-c-native-code-to-existing-android-studio-project) and several more I could not find an answer so...

I am trying to find a way to include some C code I have into an Android Project but without having to give the source files directly in the Android Project. I would like the Android to have available directly the compiled version of the C code. So my idea was to have a test Android app, where I included the source C code along with a `CMakeLists.txt` and it compiled (using ninja) properly and the app run correctly.
It created these output folders as shown in the picture here for different architectures.
[image: AndroidStudio]

So my idea was to extract these folders

But I am not sure how can I proceed from here.
- How can I include it to the App or even if is this enough?
- Is there any other way to include some native code to an Android App without providing the source code?
- Would it be possible to make a dummy gradle plugin and attach this code as dependency to it, so I can publish the plugin and use that same plugin in the Android App?

Comment: I doubt that's possible. For what platform was the program compiled? C is compiled for specific hardware and OS so you cannot simply take the binaries and execute them on a different platform. Only workaround I can think of is running some VM on Android.

Comment: Exactly because i read the other question i linked, i wanted to take the compiled part that android is building. As you can see the Android Studio generated compiled version for 4 different  architectures. These are the compiled ones that go into the apk if I am not mistaken. That is why I thought if I take these ones I could have a way of importing them independently to another Android App.

Comment: Android APKs absolutely support native libraries.  Please read: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds

Comment: @BadZen yes they do, but they link you suggested explains how you can add them and be compiled at android studio. I need to add precompiled code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently if you keep the name `jniLibs` Android Studio can understand the location and import the compiled code into the apk automatically since this is the default location for java native code in Android Studio.
When I did put the folder `jniLibs` in the proper location `app/src/main/jniLibs/(the architectures here)` then the Android App worked correcly without specifying anything else.

Additionally as i saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908038/adding-existing-jni-libraries-already-compiled-so-to-another-android-studio/46908643#46908643) you can also have a custom name for your folder and specify the following in your `app/build.gradle`

```
android{
   sourceSets {
       main {
           jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
       }
   }    
}
```